# Rails link_to polymorphic attribute that is potentially nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Region > Store > Device hierarchy, where each of these things can have a config_set.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :config_set, as: :configurable
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
  has_one :config_set, as: :configurable
  belongs_to :region
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :config_set, as: :configurable
  belongs_to :store
end

class ConfigSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :configurable, polymorphic: true
end
```

From the config_set `show` page, I want to generate a link to whatever `configurable` that config_set belongs to. `link_to` is using `polymorphic_url` internally, which wants either a `@device`, a `[@store, @device]`, or a `[@region, @store, @device]`. Is there a simple way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out a not very nice solution abusing the fact that to polymorphic_url `@device` and `[nil, @device]` are equivalent, combined with ruby's `try` :

```
<%= link_to 'Back', [@config_set.configurable.try(:store).try(:region), @config_set.configurable.try(:store) || @config_set.configurable.try(:region), @config_set.configurable] %>
```